# Do I need to refresh my Sqlite3 Database in NodeJS, when I insert new data?

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I am running a NodeJS programm in which I call my database and search for specific entries. In my Python consumer, I am adding values to my database, but somehow, the database gets not updated on the NodeJS side. I output both entries into the console and when I select * from my table - on my python-end, it outputs the new entries, but on the NodeJS-end, it only outputs the 3 entries, which are added before the deployment.

In my NodeJS fill I call the database, enter my query and if an entry is found, I return the value and after that, I close the connection and on the next message reopens my database:

```
function findUserByLogin(hash) {
    const db = new sqlite3.Database('./database_worker/cracked_pw.sqlite', (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
        console.log('Connected to the my database.');
    });


    var databaseCheckHash = x;
    var sql = 'SELECT cracked '
    sql += 'FROM password '
    sql += 'WHERE hash = ? '
    var sql2 = 'SELECT * from password'

    db.get(sql, hash, function(error, row) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error while checking the Database for Hash: " + error)
            return
        } else {
            try {
                db.all(sql2, [], (err, rows) => {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                    rows.forEach((row) => {
                        console.log(row.id + " " + row.hash + " " + row.cracked);
                    });
                });

                // Calling an undefined `item `variable
                console.log("length: " + (row.cracked).length)
                databaseCheckHash = row.cracked;
                printUserEmail(row.cracked)

            } catch (e) {
                if (e instanceof ReferenceError) {
                    printError(e, true);
                } else {
                    printError(e, false);
                }
            } finally {
                if (databaseCheckHash.length == 3) {

                    databaseResult = databaseCheckHash;
                    return databaseResult;

                } else {
                    sendMsgToMQ();
                }
                db.close((err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.message);
                    }
                    console.log('Close the database connection.');
                });
            }


        }

    });
}
```

On my Python consumer, I am adding new entries:

```
import pika
import sqlite3
import os
print("[DB-Worker]Worker (consumer) storing information to database")

print("[DB-Worker]Check if SQLite database exists")
db = "./database_worker/cracked_pw.sqlite"

if not os.path.isfile(db):
    print("[DB-Worker]Database does not exist, creating now")
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS password (id INTEGER, hash VARCHAR type UNIQUE, cracked VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY(id))')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
else:
    print("[DB-Worker]DB exists")

def storage_callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(f"[DB-Worker]Attempting to save {body}")
    message = body.decode('UTF-8')
    list = message.split(',')
    hash = list[0]
    password = list[1]
    print(f"[DB-Worker]] hash is {hash}, cracked pw is {password}")
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO password (hash, cracked) values ("'+hash+'", "'+password+'")')
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM password")
    print(cur.fetchall())
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    print(f"[DB-Worker]Committed to database")
```

Do I need to somehow, reload or kind of refresh my database on my NodeJS server side?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the node.js process pick up the changes if you stop and start it?

Comment: and is there anything interesting or different about the file system the database is being written to?